# Error: Bad state: Future already completed while awaiting for futures to complete - how to catch?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-video-player

I am having this exception on iOS (Android's OK):

> flutter: Error: Bad state: Future already completed

And I am trying to understand and fix it.

Therefore I wanted to know:

1. How to catch this error? My try doesn't catch it at all nor the cleanup is called back;
2. How could I investigate such an error, any starting direction or idea is warmly welcomed.

My code is as follows

```dart
void asyncInit() async {

  // Blah blah

  final futures = <Future>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {             
    futures.add(prepareVideoStreamControllerAtIndex(i));      
  }
  
  try {
    await Future.wait(futures, cleanUp: (value) {
      debugPrint("Error while waiting for stream controller: $value");
    });
   } catch (e) {
     debugPrint(
            "Error while waiting for stream controllers (await Future.wait(futures): $e");
   }
   
   // == Start the first video

   _cachedVideoPlayerControllers[0]?.play();
   setState(() => _isCachingFirstVideoStream = false);
   
   // blah blah
}
```

And my future code is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

  /// Add video controller in the cache for [itemIndex] slot
Future<void> prepareVideoStreamControllerAtIndex(int itemIndex) async {
  final videoUrl = videoStreamUrlAtIndex(itemIndex);

  final controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl,
    videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(
    mixWithOthers: true,
  ));
    

  _cachedVideoPlayerControllers[itemIndex] = controller;

  try {
    await controller.initialize();
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint("Error while initializing video stream controller: $e");
  }
}
```